# sql convert vertical table to horizontal using stored procedure or function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to horizontalize a table using a stored procedure but I have some issues.
I'm using SQL Server 9.0.5000

My final target would be to have a function or a stored procedure where I can pass the parameters of database/table to run my query which will horizontalize my table.

suppose that I would query the table V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951

i have more fields i woluld like to horizontalize but let's keep it short for the example. Suppose i would use HisRespondent, HisResult, HisInterviewer (and HisCallNumber which is the number of the attempt i am using to horizontali

to horizontalize I am using a syntax like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  HisRespondent, 
HisInterviewer1 = (select HisInterviewer FROM V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951 where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), 
HisResult1 = (select HisResult FROM V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951 where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1)
HisInterviewer2 = (select HisInterviewer FROM V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951 where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), 
HisResult2 = (select HisResult FROM V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951 where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2)
...
FROM V1DB2005.dbo.Historic_MV200951 as H
```

It works but when I have different projects or different locations i need to replace them manually and I was thinking to maybe use a stored procedure or views but i'm not sure how to do that...

I tried creating a stored procedure using 2 parameters (project and server) concatenating some strings to generate my sql query and then run it, the problem is that it works only for the first 4 attempts probably because the string is too long at it is truncated:

```
create proc HistoricOriz 
    (
        @srvr nvarchar(100),
        @project nvarchar(100)
    )
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT  HisRespondent, 
                HisInterviewer1 = (select HisInterviewer FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), HisResult1 = (select HisResult FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), HisCallDate1 = (select HisCallDate FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), HisCallDuration1 = (select HisCallDuration FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), HisEndQuestion1 = (select HisEndQuestion FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), HisPause1 = (select HisPause FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=1), 
                HisInterviewer2 = (select HisInterviewer FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), HisResult2 = (select HisResult FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), HisCallDate2 = (select HisCallDate FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), HisCallDuration2 = (select HisCallDuration FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), HisEndQuestion2 = (select HisEndQuestion FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2), HisPause2 = (select HisPause FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=2),   
                HisInterviewer3 = (select HisInterviewer FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3), HisResult3 = (select HisResult FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3), HisCallDate3 = (select HisCallDate FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3), HisCallDuration3 = (select HisCallDuration FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3), HisEndQuestion3 = (select HisEndQuestion FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3), HisPause3 = (select HisPause FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=3),
                HisInterviewer4 = (select HisInterviewer FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4), HisResult4 = (select HisResult FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4), HisCallDate4 = (select HisCallDate FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4), HisCallDuration4 = (select HisCallDuration FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4), HisEndQuestion4 = (select HisEndQuestion FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4), HisPause4 = (select HisPause FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' where HisRespondent=H.HisRespondent and HisCallNumber=4)
                FROM ' + @srvr + '.dbo.Historic_' + @project + ' as H'
    execute sp_executesql @sql
end

exec HistoricOriz @srvr='V1DB2005',  @project='MV200951';
```

I could shorten the syntax adding use @srvr; but it won't be enough in certain situations or if i have longer queries...

sorry if this has been already asked but i am not an expert and i'm struggling with that....

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL PIVOT command might be what you need. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Comment: Careful, that code is **very** open to SQL injection. Before anything, you **need** to fix that. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)